# Have something in coils

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

[Question editted following @Davo comment]

I stumbled upon this [riddle](http://riddlesphinx.com/i-am-a-ship-that-can-be-made-to-ride-the-greatest-waves-i-am-not-built-by-objects-but-built-by-minds-what-am-i/), which is referring to oil:

> It flows out of the soil,
>   It burns you if it boils,
>   And holds us in its coils,
>   More valuable than gold,
>   As black as it is old.

It seems that the meaning of *coils* here is as *in its clutches*, but is it acceptable to use *hold something in coils* in a similiar manner?

Comment: Perhaps your independent research failed to show that is used as *in its clutches,* except it alludes to something with tentacles.

Comment: Is this lyrics/a poem?

Comment: Its a riddle, from [here](https://gamehelp.guru/riddle-me-that-itch-mania-rhymes-1-19-it-flows-out-of-the-soil-it-burns-you-if-it-boils-and-holds-us-in-its-coils-more-valuable-than-gold-as-black-as-it-is-old-answer/)

Comment: I hope it's not an allusion to vaping!

Comment: Is it 'toil'? 'roil'? 'soil'? 'bloil'? Something about this...

Comment: It's a poem. Anything goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While *clutches*, meaning a tight power over or grasp of something, could be substituted for *coils*, *coils* is at once a more evocative image and, possibly, a clever play on words.

Unless the coils of a rope or the like are explicitly mentioned, a reference to *coils* in literature is a reference to being trapped and then strangled in the coils of a serpent. The [serpent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/serpent) — as OLD defines it,

> *literary* A large snake.
>
> - A biblical name for Satan.
> - A dragon or other mythical snake-like reptile.

— is predominantly a negative symbol in both the Greco-Roman and Judeo-Christian traditions, the lenses through which Western Civilization interpreted the world until the modern era. Mythical snakes are almost invariably monsters (e.g. Leviathan, Typhon, lindworms) or descendants or components of monsters (Gorgons, the Hydra, basilisks). In the Bible, of course, a serpent brings about the [Fall of Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_man), and Jesus decries his enemies as *[Ye serpents, ye generation of vipers](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2023%3A33&version=KJV)*.

However unfair this is to the animals (who like wolves, pigs, sharks, bats, vultures, and others have suffered from irrational fear and hatred), it remains that snakes are associated with wickedness and treachery. To be caught in the coils of a snake is to be in grave peril indeed.

Contemporary human society is aware that the centrality of oil in the industrial economy and technological society has led to revolution, economic ruin, war, environmental degradation, and other ills. It is not necessary to specify the peril; any that the reader wishes to project will be adequate.

You can find other examples of this metaphor in contemporary writing. There are of course examples where the comparison to a serpent is direct, or very clear, as with these in [COHA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/):

> I … beheld from the summit a long succession of hazy hills, valleys, and forests, with the Blue Ridge Mountains bounding the distance, like some mighty monster, enclosing the world in its coils. — *Campaigns of a Non-Combatant, and His Romaunt Abroad During the War*, George Alfred Townshend, 1866

> [T]he river twines and twists around the foot of Dead River Mountain, dark and glistening and silent, as though it waited, listening and moving very imperceptibly, to gather a victim in its coils. — *Arundel*, Kenneth Roberts, 1930

> The night still pressed around her, wrapping her tight in its coils, imprisoning her movements. — *Treasure of the Sun*, Christina Dodd, 1991

But the serpent may be implicit as well.

> A case may be made that World War II freed the United States from its obsession of a dangerous Europe preying on its innocence and entangling the nation in its coils. — *NATO 1948: The Birth of the Transatlantic Alliance*, Lawrence Kaplan, 2007

Less obviously, and perhaps not intentionally, there is a lesser sense of *coil* meaning plumbing; in the OED's words,

> 4a. An arrangement of a wire, piping, sheet metal, etc., in a series of concentric or symmetrical curves or windings.

Oil thus has *coils* also in the sense that its extraction, transportation, refining, and storage entail many thousands of miles of pipes and pipelines, which form part of the landscape of an industrial economy and technological society.